# Find documents where Date is within one minute from now

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to do two things, in two seperate queries:

1. Find all documents where the date field is now, or within 60 seconds from now
2. Find all documents where the date field is any day, but the same time as now or within 60 seconds from now, again ignoring the exact day.

For the first problem I have tried `date: { $geq: new Date(), $lt: (new Date()).setMinutes((new Date()).getMinutes() + 1)}`,

however I get the error `Can't use $geq with Date`. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison operator for "Equal or Greater Than" is $GTE.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/